# SQL select set zero to not listed

Tags: php, sql, select

I have SQL table with records of my runs. I do not run every day ofcause. For example, my output

```
  (select * from table where week=12)
```

looks like this:

```
day1 = 10km
day3 = 8,5km
day6 = 10km
```

How can I set days when I do not run to 0km? I would like to have output like this:

```
day1 = 10km
day2 = 0km
day3 = 8,5km
day4 = 0km
day5 = 0km
day6 = 10km
day7 = 0km
```

Few rows of my table:

```
DATE          WEEK    MONTH    DISTANCE
1520636400    201810  201803   4.60
1520031600    201809  201803   8.01
1520809200    201811  201803   8.03
1520809200    201811  201803   12.00
```

Comment: You could either make another table with all days and left join this table on it. Or you could do it with php?

Comment: Could you please post the table schema and some records?

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: why not achive this by programming language (php or any other language) ?

Comment: How can I upload a small screenshot of my table?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution will be this query:

```
select
  temp.d, isnull(real.km,0)
from (
  select 'day1' d union all
  select 'day2' d union all
  select 'day3' d union all
  select 'day4' d union all
  select 'day5' d union all
  select 'day6' d union all
  select 'day7' d
  ) temp
  left join (
    select 'day1' d, 10 km union all
    select 'day3' d, 8.5 km union all
    select 'day6' d, 6 km 
  ) real
  on temp.d=real.d
```

You can use a template of the days you always want to be present and left join with them, choosing the km for matching records

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a table for days which will include all days of week

```
Create Table Days
(
  id int not null primary key,
  day varchar(20)
)
```

In your entry table add foreign key of days table.

After completing this use this as final query

```
select e.distance,case when e.dayid is null then '0km' 
else e.distance end as distance,  d.day  from entrytable e
right join 
Days d
on d.id = e.daysid and e.week = yourvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$mysqlResultArray = array('day1' => '10km', 'day3' => '8,5km', 'day6' => '10km');
$daysArray = array('day1','day2','day3','day4','day5','day6','day7');
foreach($daysArray as $day){
   if(!in_array($day, $mysqlResultArray)){
     $mysqlResultArray[$day] = '0km';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [dates table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx) in your database or build a function which returns dates between given to boundary dates, then left join your table in a select with dates table. Join condition is the date. If your table does not have a value display it as 0

With sample data as follows, you can check the given query

```
/*
create table dailydistance (
    [date] date,
    distance decimal(10,2)
)
insert into dailydistance values ('20180410','4.60')
insert into dailydistance values ('20180412','6.30')
insert into dailydistance values ('20180413','2.00')
insert into dailydistance values ('20180416','7.40')
*/
select
    dt.date,
    isnull(dd.distance,'0.00') as distance
from [dbo].[DateTable]('20180401','20180430') as dt
left join dailydistance dd
    on dd.date = dt.date
```